# Re-Posting this - Terminal Server - Group Policy prevent command line [2]

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, windows-command-prompt

The actual post was here but it was an [old thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/55673/terminal-server-group-policy-prevent-command-line) and I couldn't find an answer online or with the infrastructure guys from my company as most of them already left.

I have a Windows 2008 Terminal Server. Terminal Server Configuration(licence server, session broker, etc) is managed by group policy. If i want to disable logon via:

```
change logon /disable
```

The Error Message: `"Connections are currently ENABLED by Group Policy for this machine, unable to change."`

Is there a smart way to fix this?

I would like to do this using a CMD as the company is moving towards automation but I am stuck.  I'll really appreciate a response or answer to this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to delete the registry value that corresponds to the Group Policy setting that controls this:

```
change logon /disable
Connections are currently ENABLED by Group Policy for this machine, unable to change.

reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v fDenyTSConnections /f
The operation completed successfully.

change logon /disable
Session logins are currently DISABLED
```

The policy setting is:

Node: Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections

Policy: Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services

Note that if Group Policy is reapplied, logons may be re-enabled.